# How to use a `build` subdirectory when compiling in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio, knitr, pdflatex

To avoid cluster in my working directories I like using a `build` subdirectory, however I cannot figure out how to do this when compiling via RStudio.

From the research I have done trying to find a solution here on Stack Exchange and other websites I think I have to use `--output-directory=build` somewhere but I cannot find anywhere in RStudio to add this line.

How do I compile Knitr and LaTeX documents with RStudio and have the output in a build subdirectory?

Comment: Since I also use Texmaker I have tried this suboptimal option of changing the Knitr user command from 
`"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe" -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"` to add `,output = normalizePath('build/%')` in `knit2pdf` but this gives the error
`*** (job aborted, no legal \end found) ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`